# Error while running hiera hash

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to call `hiera_hash` in my module but I am getting an error while excecuting. This is how I'm calling from my module:

```
$data = hiera_hash('profile')
```

Below is my yaml file:

```
profile:
 container:
  - default
  - full
```

Below is my error:

> Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, (): could not find expected ':' while scanning
>    a simple key at line 2 column 1 at C:/manifests/init
>   .pp:3:15 on node   xxxxx

Comment: can you try giving one more space before container?

Comment: @karthikeayan yeah I tried giving space before container and aswell I tried giving space before : but no luck

Comment: The error you get is in some `C:/manifests/init.pp` file. Are you sure this references the YAML file and not some syntax error elsewhere?

Comment: Note, by the way, that you do not need to use `hiera_hash()` just because you expect the datum you want to retrieve to be a hash.  `hiera_hash()` *does* return a hash, but so does `hiera()` if that's the form the datum takes.  Use `hiera_hash()` when, and *only* when, you want to perform a [hash-merge lookup](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/latest/lookup_types.html#hash-merge).  You certainly don't need that for the data you've presented.

Comment: Thanks all!! it worked after I changed the flow in my Hiera.yaml as below: '---
:backends:
  - yaml
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::osfamily}/%{::environ}/%{::appname}/definition"
  - "%{::osfamily}/%{::environ}/%{::appname}/profile"
:yaml:
  :datadir: 'C:\Aviva\Application\Provisioning\hiera\var'